# How to check, if the class is abstract, at compile time?

Tags: c++, abstract-class, compile-time, static-assert

By an abstract class I mean the class with at least one pure virtual method. I want the compilation to fail, if the check shows that the class is **not** abstract.

Is it even possible?

Comment: Try to create an instance of it? If it is an abstract class, you can not have instances of that class.

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie trying to create an instance of it can also make compilation fail due to other reasons, such as a private constructor, so this isn’t a bullet-proof solution.

Comment: @rightfold you are right, but for example in [this](http://ideone.com/pNogKP) case, both errors are considered.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`std::is_abstract`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_abstract).

```
#include <type_traits>

static_assert(std::is_abstract<T>(), "T ought to be abstract.");
```

See it [in action](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e55967d1a0c3b180).

Comment: Wow, didn't know such traits exist in STL.

Comment: This doesn't compile in Visual Studio 2013. The compiler doesn't think std::is_abstract<> is a constant expression!

Comment: You need to use ::value in VS2013.