# static_assert(std::is_abstract) causes a compiler error in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-assert

When compiling this line of code in Visual Studio 2013:

```
static_assert(!std::is_abstract<int>(), "test");
```

this compiler error is output:

```
expected constant expression
```

But the code snippet is presented as an answer in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369036/how-to-check-if-the-class-is-abstract-at-compile-time). Is this a bug in the MSVC++ compiler? Is there a workaround?

Comment: [Visual Studio 2013 doesn't support `constexpr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) so the `is_abstract<int>::operator bool()` method can't be used in a constant expression. But you may access the value directly with `is_abstract<int>::value`.

Comment: Actually it doesn't work in VS2015 either, which supports `constexpr` partially

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSVC has no constexpr, use std::is_abstract< int >::value